# JavaFX TextField only Focued state changeable with css

Tags: java, javafx

So I am trying to change the color of the text written inside a textfield using a CSS file with javafx. The problem is, no matter what I try, i am only able to change the color when I have the textField selected.

I already tried every changeable variable of a textfield that one can change and yes, I have tried seperating the focused and non-fucused state of the textField. I dont know what could be the problem.

This is what I tried:
(-fx-secondary-light, -fx-text-primary are colors defined by me. Removing them and using hex values doesnt chnge anything)

```
.textFieldSecondary {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
}
```

This changes the background color for both focused and not focused and only changes the fonts when I am focused

```
.textFieldSecondary {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
}
.textFieldSecondary:focused {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
}
```

Same result with that

```
.textFieldSecondary {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
}
```

If I do only the focused it works: If I am not focused, its completely plain, if I am focused, it all shows right

To my understanding the first case should only change the non-focused state, the second both, and the third only the focused. But i doesnt work.
What is my fault that prevents me from changing both states?

This is my full CSS File:

```
* {
    -fx-white: #FFFFFF;

    -fx-primary-default: #333333;
    -fx-primary-light: #696969;

    -fx-secondary-default: #DB5A42;
    -fx-secondary-light: #DE6953;

    -fx-text-primary: #FFFFFF;
    -fx-error-primary: #FF0000;
    -fx-closeButton: #FF0000;
}

.buttonPrimary {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-primary-default;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-white;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-border-radius: 5;
}

.buttonSecondary {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-default;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-border-width: 3;
    -fx-border-radius: 5;
}

.buttonExit {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-closeButton;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.buttonBack {
    -fx-background-color: -fx-secondary-default;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-image: url('/Resources/backArrow.png');
    -fx-background-position: center;
    -fx-background-size: 231px 68px;
}

.textFieldSecondary {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
}

.textFieldSecondaryError {
    -fx-background-color:  -fx-secondary-light;
    -fx-border-color: -fx-error-primary;
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-radius: 2;
    -fx-text-fill: -fx-text-primary;
}
```

Comment: What are `-fx-text-primary` and `-fx-secondary-light`?

Comment: colors defined in the css file, if i put the hex values there its the same result

Comment: I can not reproduce this. Using `.text-field {
    -fx-background-color: red;
    -fx-text-fill: blue;
    -fx-prompt-text-fill: green;
}` works as expected, even if the textfield is not focused.

Comment: I added my whole css file, maybe theres a error somewhere? everything else besides textfields works just fine

Comment: Which Java and JavaFX version do you use?

Comment: okay, so apparently when i create a new fxml and try it there it works, so it has to be a problem with one of my fxmls. I use Java 12

Comment: Ok, your CSS file looks OK, and works for me. So the problem has to be elsewere.

Comment: well I redid the whole File and it works now, no idea what caused that. Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 1):

**Try to do with code**

This is a Simple way to change inner text-fill color in Text Field JAVAFX

```
private void setTextColor() {
    txtReferance.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
    txtName.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
    txtNIC.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
    txtMobileNo.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
    txtEmail.setStyle("-fx-text-inner-color: red;");
}
```

and call that setTextColor() method in initialize Or constructor. txtReferance , txtName ,txtNIC ,txtMobileNo,txtEmail are the text Fields Ids

**OR using CSS**

```
-fx-text-inner-color: red;
```

this is worked for me.